# Erro na execucao do google maps, referente a erro de script

Tags: google, maps, panel

```
Estou com um erro na chamada do painel do google maps, em html:

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

    insira o código aqui

Script error
http://maps.google.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/24/12/intl/pt_br/util.js

A linha que chama é 
mapDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"))

Código completo:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.24&language=pt-BR'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var map, geocoder;
var mapDisplay, directionsService;
function initialize() {
var myOptions = {zoom: 15,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var enderDe =  'Rua Maranhao, 1575,VILA VELHA,ES,29101340';
var enderAte = 'Rua Maranhao, 2575,VILA VELHA,ES,29101340';
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': enderAte, 'region' : 'BR'},trataLocs);
initializeDirections ();
calcRota (enderDe, enderAte);
}
function initializeDirections () {
 directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 mapDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
 mapDisplay.setMap(map);
 mapDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("panel"));
}
function calcRota(endDe, endPara) {
    var request = {
        origin:endDe, 
        destination:endPara,
        waypoints: [{location:'VARZEA ALEGRE,,SANTA MARIA DE JETIBA,ES,'},{location:'GARRAFAO,,SANTA MARIA DE JETIBA,ES,'}],
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        mapDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
function trataLocs (results, status) {
var elem = document.getElementById('msg');
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
 map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map, 
position: results[0].geometry.location  });
if (results.length > 1) {
 var i, txt = '<select style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;width=550px;" onchange="mostraEnd(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">';
 elem.innerHTML = 'O endereço exato não foi localizado - há ' +  results.length.toString() + ' resultados aproximados.<br />';
 for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
 txt = txt + '<option value="' + i.toString() + '"';
 if (i == 0)
   txt = txt + ' selected="selected"'; 
 txt = txt + '>' + results[i].formatted_address + '</option>';
}
txt = txt + '</select>'
 elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + txt;
 }
} else
 elem.innerHTML = 'Erro no tratamento do endereço :<br /><b>' + status + '</b>';
 }
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload='initialize();' style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;margin:5px 0 5px 0;'>
  <center> 
    <div id='msg'></div> 
    <div id='map_canvas' style='width:550px;height:450px'></div>
    <div id='panel' style='width:550px;height:450px'></div>
    </center> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nilton, por favor adiciona a tua questão o código completo que faz a chamada ao maps, bem como se posśivel adiciona a tag javascript a ela, para melhorar a visualização para quem realmente pode entender do assunto.

Comment: @BrunoBermann  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><script type="text/javascript" src=""></script><script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.24&sensor=false&language=pt-BR'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>var map, geocoder;
var mapDisplay, directionsService;function initialize() {
var myOptions = {zoom: 15,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

Comment: @BrunoBermann geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();var enderDe =  'Rua Maranhao, 1575';var enderAte = 'Rua Maranhao,2575';geocoder.geocode( { 'address': enderAte, 'region' : 'BR'},trataLocs);initializeDirections ();calcRota (enderDe, enderAte);
}

Comment: Nilton, por favor edita tua pergunta para dar maior visibilidade ao código. Vou analisar e se descobrir algo encaminho uma resposta.

Comment: Resolvido com ajuste no regedit. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION